# How to use prototype pattern with correct meaning?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am trying to understand the Prototype desgining pattern.

Here is the sample code.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Prototype proto = new Prototype();

        Dog d = new Dog();

        Dog clone ;//= (Dog)proto.getClone(d);

        clone = (Dog) d.makeCopy();

        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(clone);
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        //System.out.println();
        //d.setval("test");
        //System.out.println(clone.getVal());

    }
}
```

It is clear how a clone of dog is created in a prototype.

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Dog clone ;
clone = (Dog) d.makeCopy();
```

But without doing all these steps, can't we simply do this?

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Dog clone = d;
```

The only usage I can think of is dynamically creating clone objects through Prototype as we can pass any subclass of superclass of Dog type.

Am I correct? Or is there anything else that needs to add to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about the Prototype Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739240/questions-about-the-prototype-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Dog clone = d;
```

does not create a copy of the object. You will have the same object linked from variables `d` and `clone`. You can check that by adding some field to your Dog class and assigning it's value in clone. Check the d's value after that. It should be the same.

The proper implementation of `makeCopy` should call a `new` operator, which creates a brand new object and populates it with prototype's data.